# How do I make lens filters work?

Tags: unity, unity-dash, lenses

I have created an RSS feed lens based on [unity-lens-python](http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~unity-team/unity-lens-sample/unity-place-python/files), but I cannot get the filters to work. I've also tried the original unity-lens-python and the filter does not work in that lens either.

My lens can be found on my [Google documents page](https://docs.google.com/open?id=0B8R6dIjrwr6GMGQwOTA0ZTUtZDE2ZS00ZDg5LTkxNTItZWNkMjAzM2VhZjYw), and it would be great if someone could have a look into it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you connect to the "filters-changed" signal and update your results when it's fired. For an example see the one-hundred-scopes project where this is used. ( http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~davidc3/onehundredscopes/desura/view/head:/src/unity-scope-desura#L34 )

Comment: Thank you so much. I've been struggling with this for days. This solved my problem.